# How to get row number of a widget inside a flextable?

Tags: gwt, row, flextable

I found this code on internet but not sure it is the optimum solution

```
public int getWidgetRow(Widget widget, FlexTable table) {

        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
          for (int col = 0; col < table.getCellCount(row); col++) {
            Widget w = table.getWidget(row, col);
            if (w == widget) {
              return row;
            }
          }
        }

        return -1;
  }
```

Why FlexTable does not have a function to get a row no of a widget inside it?

Any other better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simple way:

```
        table.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
                 int rowIndex = table.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
            } 
        });
```

Comment: But i got a button inside a cell in flextable. so I click the button & not actually click a cell of flextable. Then how o code it?

Comment: whats happening now ??when your button clicked control not coming in to onClick method ??